# How do I replace multiple characters in a String?

Tags: kotlin

How do I replace multiple characters in a String?

Like Java's [replaceAll(regex:replacement:)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) function.

```java
str.replaceAll("[$,.]", "") //java code
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44197064/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-sub-string-in-kotlin) answer is very close but I want to change more than one character at the same time.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44197064/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-sub-string-in-kotlin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a sub string in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44197064/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-sub-string-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`[$,.]` is regex, which is the expected input for Java's `replaceAll()` method. Kotlin, however, has a class called `Regex`, and `string.replace()` is overloaded to take either a String or a Regex argument.

So you have to call `.toRegex()` explicitly, otherwise it thinks you want to replace the String literal `[$,.]`. It's also worth mentioning that `$` in Kotlin is used with String templates, meaning in regular strings you have to escape it using a backslash. Kotlin supports raw Strings (marked by three `"` instead of one) which don't need to have these escaped, meaning you can do this:

```
str = str.replace("""[$,.]""".toRegex(), "")
```

In general, you need a Regex object. Aside using `toRegex()` (which may or may not be syntactical sugar), you can also create a Regex object by using the constructor for the class:

```
str = str.replace(Regex("""[$,.]"""), "")
```

Both these signal that your string is regex, and makes sure the right `replace()` is used.

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy to work with regular expressions, then refer to the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50270101/1071320). If you're curious as to how you can achieve this without regular expressions, continue reading.

You can use the `String.filterNot(predicate:)` and `Set.contains(element:)` functions to define a `String.removeAll` extension function as follows:

```kotlin
/**
 * @param charactersToRemove The characters to remove from the receiving String.
 * @return A copy of the receiving String with the characters in `charactersToRemove` removed.
 */
fun String.removeAll(charactersToRemove: Set<Char>): String {
    return filterNot { charactersToRemove.contains(it) }
}
```

You would call on this function as follows: `myString.removeAll(setOf('$', '.'))`